# How can i export the test result of WinRT Unit testing report?

Tags: unit-testing, windows-runtime

I have written the unit test cases for WinRT, but I am not able to export the test result into HTML or XML format which I can use for further process. Please suggest me where I can find the test result details.

Comment: I dont mind the down voting if it corrects me in anyway. Without providing any comments or feedback why you down vote, dont do downvoting which is not fair.